# Can't get Value from Listview Android

Tags: android, listview

i'm new to android, lets say i had edit text inside listview and i try to copy the value to text view , but when i want to get the value of text view in activity its only get some value, not  all .. i use getChildAt and got some value of textview not at all, i try to use getAdapter().getView() and got all value of orderCodeDetailId, but cannot get all dummyImei value.. 
Here is my Code:-
**this is my adapter:**

```
EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edit_imei);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dummyImei);
        textView.setText(s);
    }
});
```

**this is my listener in Activity:**

```
btnS = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
btnS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        for(int i = 0;i<=lv.getCount();i++){
            View ha = lv.getChildAt(i);
            //View za = lv.getAdapter().getView(i,null,null);

            TextView dataOrderDetailCode = (TextView)ha.findViewById(R.id.orderCodeDetailId);
            String orderCodeDetail = dataOrderDetailCode.getText().toString();

            TextView dataOrderDetailImei =(TextView)ha.findViewById(R.id.dummyImei);
            String orderImeiDetail = dataOrderDetailImei.getText().toString();

            new InputImeiAcitivity.postImeiOrder().execute(orderCodeDetail,orderImeiDetail);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear! check https://stackoverflow.com/help to know how to ask a question. 
Where is your adapter?

Comment: Specify what is that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Are your EditText and Button inside your listView? because they don't seem to be.